# Prevent XSS in javascript on data received by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

I receive data from a database and adds the result to an HTML element using jQuery ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getDatabaseData.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $("#message-div").html(response[0].user_input_message);
    }
});
```

Here is the getDatabaseData.php that gets and returns the data from the database:

```
$messages = $CFG_DB->select("SELECT user_input_message FROM messages");
echo json_encode($messages);
```

Imagine for example if user_input_message contain the following text:

```
<script>XSS Attack code goes here</script>
```

My questions are:

1. Will there be an XSS issue when doing like this?
2. In case there is an issue, how can I prevent it?

Without ajax, when printing the data using PHP I just use htmlentities to prevent XSS, but I have not seen any similar for javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when printing the data using PHP I just use htmlentities to prevent XSS

The equivalent is to use `text()` instead of `html()`.

Comment: So if I use text() instead of html() then I am safe, that is awesome!
But, most of the time I have some html code that should be added at the same time, for example:
$("#message-div").html("<div>The message is: " + response[0].user_input_message + "</div>");
What to do then?

Comment: I created a new post regarding my question in the previous comment. Feel free to answer it if you know the answer, thanks:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590792/prevent-xss-in-jquery-html