# Prevent XSS in jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I receive data from a database using ajax and then adds it together with HTML code to the website using the .html() jQuery function, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getDatabaseData.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        $("#message-div").html(getMessagesHtml(response));
    }
});

function getMessagesHtml(messages){
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
        result += 
            "<div>" + 
                "<p>Name: " + messages[i].name + "</p>" + 
                "<p>Message: " + messages[i].message + "</p>" + 
            "</div>";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is the getDatabaseData.php that gets and returns the data from the database:

```
$messages = $CFG_DB->select("SELECT name, message FROM messages");
echo json_encode($messages);
```

Imagine for example if message contain the following text:

```
<script>XSS Attack code goes here</script>
```

**My questions are:**

1. Will there be an XSS issue when doing like this?
2. In case there is an issue, how can I prevent it?

I guess that using text() instead of html() is not an option in this case since I also add html code.

Without javascript, when printing the data using PHP I just use htmlentities on the variables received from the database to prevent XSS, for example htmlentities(messages[i].name) and htmlentities(messages[i].message). But I have not seen any similar for javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting  text with user input is the safest way. Instead of creating html strings, create elements instead

Something like:

```
function getMessagesHtml(messages){

  return messages.map(function(o){
    var $div = $('<div>');
    $div.append($('<p>', {text: "Name: " + o.name}));
    $div.append($('<p>', {text: "Message: " + o.message}));
    return $div;
  });

}
```

---

Per comments an alternative is create a sanitizing helper function that creates an element that passes the input string as text to the element and returns that text

```
function text(str){
   return $('<div>',{text:str}).text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I would prefer if there was another solution. Your suggestion would in my opinion make the code harder to read, and to write. And it would require huge changes to my code since I use the technique in my example everywhere on my entire website and with much more complicated html element tree structures etc.
Something like this would be awesome: "<p>Message: " + text(messages[i].message) + "</p>", but maybe there is no such thing in jQuery/Javascript.

Comment: The "function text(str){ return $('<div>'{text:str}).text();}" is awesome if it is secure, thanks! And I guess I can just replace <div> with <span> if I want tu use span instead. Any specific reasons why I should use <div>? Another question, do you know if there will be any big performance issues if using this about 200 times in one page load?

Comment: element used is irrelevant and 200 times is not a significant overhead. Pass some html as part of `message` and will see that it will display it as text and not rendered html